VirtualBox 7.0.18, DnD (Drag and Drop) not working from LMDE6 Guest to LMDE6 Host. vboxdrv, vboxnetadp and vboxnetfit not running
Host and Guest are Linux Mint Debian Edition LMDE6, 64Bit with Cinnamon Desktop.
VirtualBox 7.0.18 is installed in the host.
The guest has the guest extension 7.0.18 installed.
Shared Clipboard works in booth directions.
DnD (Drag and Drop) for files, works from Host to Guest.
They are no Error message by GUI by not working DnD and Drope from Guest to Host.
Disabling firewall on Host and Guest system, don't change this.
The question is not comparable to the following questions, which refer
to Ubuntu-based Linux Mint versions:

Drag-and-drop files into Linux Mint from virtualized Windows 7

The question is also not comparable to the follow question, which refer to Wayland based dedian version and dont reffer to vboxdrv, vboxnetadp and vboxnetfit not running.

VirtualBox: error while trying to perform a drag and drop operation from guest to host

Possible starting points for a solution:

LMDE6 is based on Debian 12.x, but as far as I know Debian 12.x uses Wayland and LMDE6 still uses X11.
About 10 years ago, in some Linux versions for DnD, you had to configure something for Xorg server on /etc/X11/xorg.conf. This may also be necessary with today's LMDE6 version.

Possibly three kernel modules for VirtualBox should actually be loaded by one of the following two files. In my case, however, these files do not contain any such entries:
/etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf
/etc/*modules

vboxdrv
vboxnetadp
vboxnetfit

Ok, lets check the Kernel driver are loaded or not:
lsmod | grep vboxdrv
# no output, that's looks for me vboxdrv not running

lsmod | grep vboxnetadp
# no output, that's looks for me vboxnetadp not running

lsmod | grep vboxnetflt
# no output, that's looks for me vboxnetflt not running

Possible I have to do one thing before asking about its loaded or not...
